# How to show augmentation ideal is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group, the augmentation map $\varepsilon:\mathbb{Z}[G]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ is defined to be $$\varepsilon\left(\sum_{g\in G}a(g)g\right)=\sum_{g\in G}a(g).$$ The kernel of $\varepsilon$ is $$I_G=\left\{\sum_{g\in G}a(g)(g-e):a(g)\in\mathbb{Z} \right\}.$$
Since $\varepsilon$ is a ring homomorphism, $I_G$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$. I wonder if someone knows how to show $I_G$ is an ideal by direct computation: $\mathbb{Z}[G]\cdot I_G\subset I_G$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g,h \in G$. Then $h(g-e)=hg-h=(hg-e) + (h-e) \in I_G$. Now extend by linearity.

BTW: The formulars $gh-e=g(h-e)+(g-e)$ and $g^{-1}-e = -g^{-1}(g-e)$ show:

> If $G$ is genated by $S \subseteq G$ then, as $\mathbb{Z}G$-module, $I_G$ is generated by $\{g-e\mid g \in S\}$.
>
> In particular, the minimal number of generators of $I_G$ as  $\mathbb{Z}G$-module is less or equal than the minimal number of generators of $G$.

I think there are some conjecture around when the two numbers agree.